# WP: How to get just one post, from one category and show it

Tags: wordpress, post, categories

**Hello guys!**
Well i have this code, that shows the one post from each category
but i need to show just ONE post, and need to set the "name" of category
i'm trying this:

```
    <?php 
$cat_args = array(
  'orderby' => 'name',
  'order' => 'ASC',
  'child_of' => 0
);

$categories =   get_categories($cat_args); 

foreach($categories as $category) { 
    echo '<dl>';
    echo '<dt> <a href="' . get_category_link( $category->name ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $category->name.'</a></dt>';

     $post_args = array(
      'numberposts' => 1,
      'category' => $category->term_id 
    );

    $posts = get_posts($post_args);

    foreach($posts as $post) {
    ?>
        <dd><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></dd>
                <div class="entry">
                            <?php the_content(); ?>
                        </div>
    <?php 
    } 
    echo '<dd class="view-all"> <a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) . '" ' . '>View all posts in ' . $category->name.'</a></dd>';
    echo '</dl>';
} 
?>
```

I then searched the codex and have not found a way to get categories by name, someone can help me??

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is [get_cat_ID](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_cat_ID).

Change `$post_args` to something like this:

```
$post_args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'cat' => get_cat_ID( 'My Category Name' )
);
```

Let me know how it goes. :)

Comment: well i changed on line 14 (following the lines on the code i have pasted)  

`$post_args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'cat' => get_cat_ID( 'destaques' );
);`

but have an error:

**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ')' in C:\wamp\www\Yazigi\wp-content\themes\responsive\sidebar-home.php on line 143**

the line 143 is:

    'cat' => get_cat_ID( 'destaques' );

Comment: I'm sorry. I had a typo in my code. There was a semi-colon at the end of the 3rd line where there shouldn't have been any line delimeter. Please try the updated code in my answer. :)

Comment: have an error =/

 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in c://path/to/file on line 160

line 160 is the last line of the script. have just a </div> =(

Comment: I would need to see the whole file. It sounds like you're missing a `)` or `;`.